# how to control where document.write writes

Tags: javascript

I want to have my javascript print a random quote out of an array. I managed to do this, but don't know how to control where it writes. I wish to write it within a div. Help?

Code:

```
quotes = [];
quotes[0] = "I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time.";
quotes[1] = "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it.";
quotes[2] = "Few things are harder to put up with than the annoyance of a good example.";
quotes[3] = "The pure and simple truth is rarely pure and never simple.";
quotes[4] = "There's no business like show business, but there are several businesses like accounting.";
quotes[5] = "Man invented language to satisfy his deep need to complain.";

//calculate a random index
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

//display the quotation
document.write("<p>" +  quotes[index] + "</p>");
```

Comment: Use DOM manipulation. http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML . `document.write` creates the output where it was called or replaces the document when it was already completely loaded. It has to be used *very* carefully and is not very useful in most cases.

Comment: Just create a `div` in your HTML (assuming you have an existing HTML document) and then use `getElementById()` to access the div, and add your content to it.

Comment: I've got nothing useful to say, but those quotes are pretty amusing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give the div an id say `divid` then use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) to get the div then [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) to set its content;

```
quotes = [];
quotes[0] = "I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time.";
quotes[1] = "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it.";
quotes[2] = "Few things are harder to put up with than the annoyance of a good example.";
quotes[3] = "The pure and simple truth is rarely pure and never simple.";
quotes[4] = "There's no business like show business, but there are several businesses like accounting.";
quotes[5] = "Man invented language to satisfy his deep need to complain.";

//calculate a random index
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

//display the quotation
document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = "<p>" +  quotes[index] + "</p>";
```

Comment: hmmmmmmm. I did that and changed the div id to match my div, but it won't work? want a link to the html as well?

Comment: @JosueEspinosa if your script tag is in the head move it to the end of the body, see http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/y3WM7/ it that doesn't work then post the link

Comment: it works when you add a button, but I just want it to run the function once automatically when the window loads.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a selector to get your div and write it's innerHtml property:

`document.getElementById("yourDivsId").innerHTML=quotes[index];`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML=quotes[index];
```

or you can use JQuery

```
$("#divID").html(quotes[index]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` will write exactly where it stands. There is no conditional target for `document.write` to end up in. However, what you are looking for is some DOM manipulation.

You should target your div, and then place the text in there like this:

html

```
<div id="divId"></div>
```

js

```
quotes = [];
quotes[0] = "I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time.";
quotes[1] = "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it.";
quotes[2] = "Few things are harder to put up with than the annoyance of a good example.";
quotes[3] = "The pure and simple truth is rarely pure and never simple.";
quotes[4] = "There's no business like show business, but there are several businesses like accounting.";
quotes[5] = "Man invented language to satisfy his deep need to complain.";

//calculate a random index
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

var mydiv = document.getElementById("divId");
mydiv.innerHTML = '<p>' +  quotes[index] + '</p>';
```